# cross join in facts and dimension

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssas, data-warehouse, multidimensional-cube

In the multidimensional cube, I have two facts (at different grain) named as : FactTestScore and Fact SubjectScore. These two facts share two dimensions- DimStudent and DimSubject. And FactTestScore has additional dimension of DimTest. I've deployed the cube without any error.

In the PowerBI to create report, when I have matrix table with Subject, Test, Student and their respective scores, the all tests are getting cross joined with all subjects. Can you please point out where I am making mistake?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain/show what this means in your case: `it looks like there is cross join happening`

Comment: I added additional explanation to the question. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you using Power BI against an external multidimensional SSAS cube? Thats an unexpected configuration. Why not just do the modelling inside Power BI and leave the SSAS Multidimensional out of it

Comment: @NancyDrew you mentioned there is an issue with a Matrix visualization. Please provide the exact name of Data Column in the format 'Table Name'[Column Name] and the DAX of the measures you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, filtering across relationships can only propagate in the direction specified.

In your diagram, there is no path from one dimension table to another without going the "wrong way". In fact, it doesn't look like they can even filter the fact tables unless the notation is the reverse of what I'm accustomed to.

Comment: Can you point me to the direction where I need to learn to fix this?

Comment: Wherever you set up your cube but I only have experience creating these models in Power BI.